# Как удалять один элемент из multiset, если в контейнере имеются дубликаты?

Tags: c++, stl, множества, multiset

При использовании метода `erase()` из мультимножества удаляются все элементы со значением параметра. Можно, конечно, класть в контейнер пару, где `first` - номер элемента, `second` - нужное значение, тогда дубликатов не будет.

Но есть ли другое решение проблемы?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multiset<int> a = {1, 1, 3};

    for(int i: a)
        cout << i << " "; // Вывод: 1 1 3

    a.erase(1);

    cout << "\n";
    for(int i: a)
        cout << i << " "; // Вывод: 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте сначала проблему. Каким образом вы предлагаете идентифицировать, какой именно из эквивалентных элементов требуется удалить?

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить код и результат вывода в текстовом виде в вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut сделано

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Работайте с итератором. Находите нужный вам элемент, вернее, ненужный :), вернее, итератор, указывающий на него - и вызывайте `erase`.

С точки зрения `multiset` все значения с одним и тем же ключом совершенно неотличимы, как какие-нибудь электроны... С вашей - они вполне могут и отличаться, и тогда ваше дело - показать мультимножеству на него итератором и сказать "ату его"...

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно удалить один элемент, делайте `erase(find(key))` вместо `erase(key)`. Разумеется, в варианте `erase(find(key))` надо добавить проверку на успешность поиска.

Однако такой способ удалит "какой-то" из эквивалентных элементов. А уж как вы предлагаете выбирать конкретный элемент для удаления и нужно ли вам его выбирать - об этом вы пока не удосужились сообщить.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, вы имели в виду метод `extract()`.

Comment: Так себе, все-таки эта функция для другого. Уж лучше find+erase.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну, может быть. Но выглядит как конкретный "не ответ".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да забавно) Наверное, вы правы, мне стоило быть внимательнее.